# Is this simple function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be defined by $f(x)=5$ if $x\leq2$ and $f(x)=6$ if $x>2$. Is it then accurate to say that $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,2]$?

Comment: Not quite. It would be accurate to say that the restriction of $f$ to $(-\infty,2]$ is continuous. But $2$ is not a point of continuity of $f$, so $f$ itself is not continuous on all of $(-\infty,2]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah yes, thanks, your answer is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Originally posted by Daniel Fischer as a comment:*

Not quite.

While it would be accurate to say that **the restriction of $f$ to $(−∞,2]$** is continuous, $f$ itself is not continuous on $(−∞,2],$ since $2$ is a point of discontinuity of $f.$

Answer (score 3):

Function is not continuous at 2!

$$\lim_{x\to2^-} f(x)=5$$

$$\lim_{x\to2^+} f(x) =6$$

Yes function is continuous on the restriction excluding the point 2 since it is constant there!